# Degree function in the "sna"-package of R ignoring valued data

Tags: r, sna

I have network data with directed and valued ties between nodes. I need to compute the in-degree for the nodes and use the "degree"-function in the "sna"-package of R, but it ignores the valued data and produce results as if the data was unvalued/binary. Here is a reproducible example:

TestData:

```
  Ego   Alter Strength
  <chr> <chr>    <num>
1 1     2         0.39
2 1     5         0.04
3 2     3         0.29
4 2     5         0.39
5 3     1         0.29
6 3     4         0.29
7 4     1         0.14
8 4     2         0.14
9 5     1         0.21
```

Script:

```
#Load packages "igraph", "sna", "ggplot2" and "ggraph"
library(igraph)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggraph)
library(intergraph)
library(sna)

#Create graph object with TestData dataframe
graphTestData <- graph_from_data_frame(TestData, directed = TRUE)

#Visualize network with tie strength as edge width
ggraph(graphTestData) + 
  geom_edge_link2(aes(width = Strength), arrow = arrow(length = unit(3, "mm")), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_edge_width(range = c(0.1, 1)) +
  geom_node_point(size=3)

#Transform igraph object to network object
networkTestData <- asNetwork(graphTestData)

#Compute in-degree for the nodes in the TestData-network
indegreeTestData <- degree(networkTestData, g=1, gmode="digraph", diag=FALSE, tmaxdev=FALSE, cmode="indegree", rescale=FALSE, ignore.eval=FALSE)

#View resulting in-degrees
View(indegreeTestData)
```

The network visualization clearly demonstrates valued ties, but the in-degrees for the nodes are clearly not using the valued data as specified by "ignore.eval=FALSE" and is distributed as follows: `1=3, 2=2, 3=1, 4=1, 5=2`

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

[image: Visualization of network that demonstrates valued ties]

Comment: are you sure that the asNetwork function retains the edge weights?  maybe check the object networkTestData (e.g. by coercing it to an adjacency matrix) to see if you have lost the edge weight values in converting from igraph to network

Comment: This is what I suspect. Thanks!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is: 1=0.64, 2=0.53, 3=0.29, 4=0,29, 5=0.43 (the sum of the incoming tie strength).